# php file_get_contents works directly but not through ajax and my url

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code to get the facebook comments for my sites url:

```
<?php
$url="http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472";
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=".$url;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
print_r($requests);
?>
```

The above works fine using the sample url that facebook provide in their tutorial. I can load the page above directly or through ajax and all is good.

The problem only arises for my url and specifically when loading it using ajax. If I load the page directly it works fine, but why when I try and load it through ajax do I get:

> function.file-get-contents: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!  HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What do you mean “through ajax”? Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: A `500` response indcates a problem at the remote party (server side). Since, in this case, the server side is owned by Facebook, there is probably little you can do about this. However in order to be sure, you need to add your actual non-working code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As a security precaution, most production PHP servers should have

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

set to off. This would cause your script to fail like you're seeing it.

Instead, use CURL. See http://snipplr.com/view/4084/

Comment: Thanks Theodore, but if this was the case then I think that the page would not work when i loaded it directly... it would also not work with the sample url that i am testing with.